# IndexError: list index out of range - when plotting images

Tags: python, image, plot, directory, index-error

Wrote a function to display 6 chest xray images from 2 different folders. The images are split into 2 folders contained inside 1 folder. (Training data is the main folder and within are 2 folders names 'PNEUMONUA' and 'NORMAL'.

When I run the function on pictures from one folder it works perfectly, when I use the function on the other folder I get "Index Error: list index out of range."

Code:

```
TRAINING_DATA = "/home/jack/Desktop/chest_xray/train/"

TEST_DATA = "/home/jack/Desktop/chest_xray/test/"

VALIDATION_DATA = "/home/jack/Desktop/chest_xray/val/"



def plot_images(path, labeled=True, max_images=6):
  amount = 0
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

  for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.jpeg'):
      if amount == max_images:
        break

      img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
      plt.subplot(231+amount)
      if labeled:
        plt.title(file.split('_')[1])
      imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

      amount += 1


plot_images(TRAINING_DATA + '/NORMAL')
#ERROR

plot_images(TRAINING_DATA + '/PNEUMONIA')
#WORKS FINE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename of the images in the 'NORMAL' folder doesn't have '_' to split (eg. IM-0115-0001.jpeg,NORMAL2-IM-0666-0001.jpeg). So you cannot split it based on '_'.

I just commented the 2 line in your code and it is working fine.

```
TRAINING_DATA = "<path>/chest_xray/train/" 


def plot_images(path, labeled=True, max_images=6):
  amount = 0
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

  for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.jpeg'):
      if amount == max_images:
        break

      img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
      plt.subplot(231+amount)
      plt.title("Normal")
      imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

      amount += 1

plot_images(TRAINING_DATA + '/NORMAL')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer! I can just replace "Normal" and 'NORMAL' with Pneumonia and it works for the other as well. Thanks! Solved!